# How should I go about reversing this USB crypto dongle?

Tags: hardware, usb

I have some kind of authentication token device delivered by a bank (that I do not expect to use for its initially-intended purpose any more). I’d like to learn how it works and whether I can recycle it for some other purpose.

On the outside, it’s a pretty simple device, resembling a USB flash memory stick. On the opposite side of the USB plug, there is a button and some LEDs. When I plug it in, the LEDs flash green, and the device reports a VID:PID pair of `0483:a188` and a description claiming it’s a ‘[software company] Smart Token ECC’.

I don’t have any software that supports this device, and don’t really know where to look for it. No luck with OpenSC: it doesn’t recognise the device at all. In fact, the token doesn’t even use the ‘smartcard’ USB device class; instead, it presents itself as a HID device. The report descriptor looks pretty strange:

```
00000000: 06ff ff09 01a1 0109 0209 0385 0115 0026  ...............&
00000010: ff00 7508 9508 8102 0904 0905 8501 1500  ..u.............
00000020: 26ff 0075 0895 0891 0209 0a09 0b85 0415  &..u............
00000030: 0026 ff00 7508 95fe b102 090c 090d 8505  .&..u...........
00000040: 1500 2609 0075 0895 08b1 0209 0609 0785  ..&..u..........
00000050: 0815 0026 4000 7508 9540 b102 0906 0907  ...&@.u..@......
00000060: 8509 1500 26ff 0075 0895 feb1 02c0       ....&..u......
```

Dumping the above reveals that this device should support exchanging reports with ID 1 on the normal channel and report IDs 4, 5, 8 and 9 on the ‘feature’ (configuration) channel. But it doesn’t agree with how the device actually works: I cannot communicate with the device other than through feature reports 4, 5 and 9, and the reports don’t even follow the format specified in the descriptor (feature report 5 should carry 8 decimal digits, one per byte, but actually carries 254 bytes). When the token receives a report it doesn’t like, it provides no answer at all and times out instead of returning an error response. Feature report 9 is read-only and provides, among other things, some kind of identification string naming the device(?) as a ‘[software company] ECC Token HW Button’. Meanwhile, pressing the button produces no effect.

I don’t know where to go from here. What else can I try?

(I fear this kind of question may be too open-ended or too narrow-scoped for the Stack Exchange Q&A format, but maybe it’s worth a shot.)

Answer (score 1):

This is only commentary with a partial answer, because your question is a bit broad (as you remark yourself). Because at this point no serious answer can be given, I'll mark it as CW.

Feitian produces a number of USB dongles (both for copy protection and `FIDO U2F + FIDO2`) that pose as HID. So that's not strange at all. Posing as HID always has the advantage that no extra driver is required (across a variety of OSes). So software talking this device needs no special properties. I don't know in which context this device is being used, but if you know and if you are able for example to see it talk to a website inside a browser, you could attempt to intercept the communication. `hid.dll` isn't in "KnownDlls" in Windows, so using a DLL placement attack on the browser you may be able to intercept the communication; even easier if you happen to be on Linux (e.g. using `LD_PRELOAD`). Unfortunately, Feitian has its own VID and it's different than the one you give.

The [Solokeys](https://github.com/solokeys/solo1) and [Nitrokeys](https://github.com/Nitrokey/nitrokey-fido2-firmware) use [STM32L432](https://github.com/solokeys/solo1/tree/master/targets/stm32l432) by STMicroelectronics, so what you're looking at could be using the exact firmware of either, or a fork of either of them; running on similar or related hardware.

Your exact VID:PID doesn't match, of course -- you probably tried that yourself -- but VID=0483 is STMicroelectronics. In general, it's also a good idea to do a web search based on the identifier Windows would assign to such a device, i.e. `USB\VID_0483&PID_A188`. (NB: interestingly the first hit of such a search yields [this link](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stsw-stm32102.html) ... which may also help to get you further along on your journey; especially if you can bring the device into such a mode. Similarly [this SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70371934) may provide leads.)

Given your description, it could be something as mundane as a FIDO2 key, which you could find out with a web browser and that USB key connected to your machine [via a test website](https://www.token2.com/tools/fido2-test/).

Last but not least, let it be known that by redacting the "software company" part and giving merely "[software company] Smart Token ECC" you have bereft us and yourself of any way to dig deeper.

Answer (score 0):

How is the device supposed to be used?
If there’s software provided by the bank, try to figure out how it communicates with the dongle.